# How to insert data in earnings table per given period

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How do I insert records into the earnings table every given period?

I have tried and it works but the problem is, in some cases, it inserts into the earnings table twice or thrice or more.

How do I make it insert uniquely?

this is what i have tried so far

```php
$deposits = self::where('status', "=", 'on')
            ->where('next_pay', "<=", $today)
            ->get();

        $deposits->reject(function ($deposit) {

        })->map(function ($deposit) use ($today) {

History::upsert(
                        array([
                            'deposit_id' => $deposit->deposit_id,
                            'user_id' => $deposit->user_id,
                            'amount' => $amount,
                            'invoice' => History::makeInvoice('earning'),
                            'ec' => $deposit->gateway->ec_id,
                            'tx_desc' => $desc,
                            'type' => 'earning',
                        ]), ['created_at', 'deposit_id', 'amount']);
});
```